# FileNotFoundException for fetching image from sdcard

Tags: java, android, gridview

Im trying to fetch all images in sdcard and populate in gridview,,,,

this is my code,, for fetching image fron sdcard

```
private ArrayList<CustomGallery> getGalleryPhotos() {
        ArrayList<CustomGallery> galleryList = new ArrayList<CustomGallery>();

        try {
            final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
            final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
                    null, null, orderBy);
            if (imagecursor != null && imagecursor.getCount() > 0) {

                while (imagecursor.moveToNext()) {
                    CustomGallery item = new CustomGallery();

                    int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

                    item.sdcardPath = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
                    galleryList.add(item);
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // show newest photo at beginning of the list
        Collections.reverse(galleryList);
        return galleryList;
    }
```

the above code returns FileNotFoundException for some images but populates available images in gridview the gridview is[image]

the top five grid has no images ,,while selecting those images gives blank area in other activity

the exception thrown is

```
03-11 11:00:40.540: E/ImageLoader(4145): /mnt/storage/Kushalam/_profileImage/CroppedImage.jpg (No such file or directory)
03-11 11:00:40.540: E/ImageLoader(4145): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/storage/Kushalam/_profileImage/CroppedImage.jpg (No such file or directory)
03-11 11:00:40.540: E/ImageLoader(4145):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
03-11 11:00:40.540: E/ImageLoader(4145):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
03-11 11:00:40.540: E/ImageLoader(4145):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:80)
03-11 11:00:40.540: E/ImageLoader(4145):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:82)
03-11 11:00:40.540: E/ImageLoader(4145):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:180)
03-11 11:00:40.540: E/ImageLoader(4145):    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:645)
03-11 11:00:40.540: E/ImageLoader(4145):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromFile(BaseImageDownloader.java:121)
03-11 11:00:40.540: E/ImageLoader(4145):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:82)
03-11 11:00:40.540: E/ImageLoader(4145):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.saveImageOnDisc(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:340)
03-11 11:00:40.540: E/ImageLoader(4145):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:232)
```

Comment: check real file is located /mnt/storage/Kushalam/_profileImage/CroppedImage.jpg

Comment: no such folder is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think mediastore return wrong path.
Try check real file in path.

```
CustomGallery item = new CustomGallery();

                int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

                item.sdcardPath = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
                File temp = new File( item.sdcardPath );
                if( temp.exists() )
                     galleryList.add(item);
```

like this.

Comment: @user39996 I don't know exactly this. I thinking this problem is real data is deleted, but mediastore is not changed or in other column check deleted such as Contacts.Group.

Comment: The problem I found is that I have been using universal image loader it also takes cache images present on disk ,so that even  deleted image if present in cache it is taken into account you showed how to avoid situation,,,any way thank you @Amadas